# Is it possible to view source codes of deployed Solana Programs?

Tags: solana-program

For example, in Etherscan it's possible to view source codes of Ethereum Smart Contracts. Is it possible to see content of Solana Programs in a similar way? I am trying to understand if deployed programs source code exposed to public.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Anchor verified programs, you can find their source code on both apr.dev and explorer.solana.com.

Example:

The Mango program `5fNfvyp5czQVX77yoACa3JJVEhdRaWjPuazuWgjhTqEH` states that it is `Anchor Verified` on the [explorer](https://explorer.solana.com/address/5fNfvyp5czQVX77yoACa3JJVEhdRaWjPuazuWgjhTqEH), and you can view all the source code for the program on the [Anchor Program Registry](https://www.apr.dev/program/5fNfvyp5czQVX77yoACa3JJVEhdRaWjPuazuWgjhTqEH?tab=Readme).

Comment: Does it mean that programs are closed-source by default? I am assuming being "Anchor Verified" is optional thing and up to program owner.

Comment: Just like other chains, programs are closed source by default

Comment: is there any update to this? APR.dev seems not to work anymore :(